# MS Access 2013 - Getting listboxes to act like excel slicers

Tags: ms-access, vba, slicers

I have form with a datasheet view of a table in a subform.

I have four different listboxes to filter specific column criteria in the subform.

If I make a selection in Listbox A, the subform auto updates to display that relevant information. Is there a way to force Listbox B-D to auto-update their selection options after the subform update to only show new available filter options? I'm attempting to get this page to work as closely as an excel slicer as possible.

I haven't found an option to reverse the link master/child fields. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I have a similar requirement; did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your course of action is as follows:
1. Create a function that updates the data source of ListBox according to the other LB selections
2. In the event AfterUpdate of each LB put the above function 
That's it!

Comment: I have a similar requirement; can you please elaborate this or provide a web resource if you have any.